# how to avoid updating parent in JPA Hibernate One-to-Many

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I made a project that using spring + hibernate (JPA Mapping). I'm using One-to-Many JPA Hibernate. i don't know whether my design itself wrong or what. I have two class Useradmin (Parent) and Tanya (child). from this i need to get the records from another table by using properties of Useradmin (parent). when I insert new record for Tanya (child) the Useradmin (Parent) updated too. I just want to insert into Tanya (child) whitout insert or update the Useradmin (Parent). could any body give me a solution, please suggest the idea to proceed :)

this is my Useradmin Class :

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserAdmin implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name="no_dana", unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false)
private String no_dana;

@Column(name="npp")
private String npp;

@Column(name="password")
private String password;

@Column(name="nama_depan")
private String nama_depan;

@Column(name="nama_tengah")
private String nama_tengah;

@Column(name="nama_belakang")
private String nama_belakang;

@Column(name="kota")
private String kota;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="useradmin")
private Set<Tanya> tanya  = new HashSet<Tanya>(0);

/**other field**//

/**setter and gettter methods**/
}
```

this is my Tanya Class :

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="tanya")
public class Tanya implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name="id_tanya", unique=true, nullable=false)
private int id_tanya;

@Column(name="subject")
private String subject;

@Column(name="isi")
private String isi;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="created")
private Date created;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="no_dana")
private UserAdmin useradmin;

/**other field**//

/**setter and gettter methods**/
}
```

and this is my controller  :

```
@RequestMapping("/user/tanya-jawab.html")
public ModelAndView listTanyaJawab(ModelMap model)throws Exception
{
    User user           = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String sessionUser  = user.getUsername();

    try{
        UserAdmin dataUser = userService.get(sessionUser);
        model.addAttribute("userData", dataUser);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("usr-tanya");
    List<Tanya> tanyajawab = tanyaService.listAllTanya();
    mav.addObject("tanyajawab", tanyajawab);
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/user/add-tanya-jawab.html", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addTanyaJawab(@ModelAttribute Tanya tanya, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception
{
    String userName = request.getParameter("hiddenUsername");

    UserAdmin useradmin = new UserAdmin();
    useradmin.setNo_dana(userName);
    System.out.println("ini"+userName);     
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();

    tanya.setUseradmin(useradmin);
    tanya.setCreated(date);
    tanyaService.save(tanya);       

    return listTanyaJawab(model);
}
```

any help will be pleasure :)

Comment: Remove the cascade from userAdmin in Tanya

Comment: @aviad that give me this error `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL`

Comment: Im not sure why it happens. Try Maybe to fetch UserAdmin by userName and than set it to tanya?

Comment: @aviad face another error ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly the issue seems to occur in your

```
public ModelAndView addTanyaJawab(@ModelAttribute Tanya tanya, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception {...}
```

method. You are creating a new Useradmin object there with:

```
    UserAdmin useradmin = new UserAdmin();
```

The issue with that is that this object is new and has not been persisted into the database yet. When you are creating a new Tanya object you are referencing it to the new UserAdmin object. However this doesn't exist.

You are either required to set a persistent UserAdmin object in your Tanya object wich has been loaded from the database beforehand or create a new UserAdmin object, add Tanya and save that instead.

Comment: how i supposed to do??

Comment: You need to fetch the UserAdmin instance from the database. Looking at your code I guess you are passing in the username through a query parameter. This is fine, since you have a unique constraint on the UserAdmin Entity for the field no_dana. However I'd suggest you should use the entity ID instead, since this is what it is for. Having the id/no_dana just query the database to load the UserAdmin instance from there, set the loaded object in your Tanya instance and save the Tanya instance.

Comment: i was replaced this code `UserAdmin useradmin = new UserAdmin();` into this code `UserAdmin useradmin = (UserAdmin)userService.get(userName);` .... voilaaaaa :D

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you can modify (even though it is not a good idea except in a test environment):

- As already mentioned in comment area remove the `cascade` attribute from the `@ManyToOne` annotation.
- Don't set `useradmin` into `tanya` object as in:

  ```
  tanya.setUseradmin(useradmin);
  ```

before `tanya` object is saved to the database. Otherwise, the persistence provider will throw `IllegalStateException` because the `cascade` attribute is removed. This is logical because your `Tanya` entity contains a foreign key to the `UserAdmin` entity the provider has to check if there is an entry for the `useradmin` in the database before it saves `tanya`.

But you created a new instance of `UserAdmin` as follows:

```
UserAdmin useradmin = new UserAdmin();
```

and therefore, there is no entry in the database. So the provider cannot save `tanya` which is pointing to a non-existent entry of `useradmin` into DB.

And some advices to improve your code:

- Remove unnecessary `@Column` annotation as long as you do not modify the default, for example in

  ```
  @Column(name="isi")
  private String isi;
  ```

  it is useless because it is the default behavior.
- Why `@SupressWarnings` annotation? This is unnecessary IMHO.
- And lastly, the following in a real environment is **very dangerous**:

  ```
  cascade = CascadeType.ALL
  ```

  Especially the CascadeType.REMOVE.